# Make intervals from two lists under conditions in Python

Tags: python

How can I make intervals from two lists under conditions in Python?

Logic behind this problem is a little bit of odd:

1. Numbers in start list can get skipped when they in an interval. Like 2011 in example 1, because 2011 is in [2010, 2012].
2. But numbers in end list can not get skipped, and raise an error. Like 2019 in example 2, because the last interval is [2015, 2016], 2019 is larger than 2016.
3. And if the last few numbers in start list are larger than the last number in end list, there will be an interval from the least number of last few numbers in start to infinity.  Like 2017, 2018 in example 3, so there will be an interval [2017, float("inf")].

Example 1:

```
start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
```

Expected outcome 1:

```
[[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, 2019]]
```

Example 2:

```
start = [2010, 2011, 2015]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
```

Expected outcome 2:

Error, because there are more numbers in end list after intervals created. (2019)

Example 3:

```
start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016]
```

Expected outcome 3:

```
[[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, float("inf")]]
```

Comment: I think you'll need to describe the logic behind your expected outcomes a bit more explicitly. Eg, in example 1, does 2011 get skipped because it's inside the first interval?

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details on what you want the function do to exactly?

Comment: Yes, numbers in start list can get skipped. But numbers in end list can not, and raise an error.

Comment: Examples are important to understand the question, but a detailed specification of the logic is essential. Your current problem is not Python coding but writing down a specification in English (or whatever) language. IMHO the current question is *unclear* because of that.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I have added description about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `iter`ators for this.

```
def create_intervals(start, end):
    start_i = iter(start)
    end_i = iter(end)

    res = [list(map(next, (start_i, end_i)))]

    for i in start_i:
        if not i in range(*res[-1]):
            try:
                res.append([i, next(end_i)])
            except StopIteration:
                res.append([i, float('inf')])
                break

    if bool(next(end_i, False)) == True:
        raise AssertionError
    return res
```

---

TESTS:

```
start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
print(create_intervals(start , end))  # -> [[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, 2019]]

start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016]
print(create_intervals(start , end))  # -> [[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, inf]]

start = [2010, 2011, 2015]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
print(create_intervals(start , end))  # -> AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your logic 100% right but this solves at least your test cases:

```
def make_intervals(start, end):
    if not start and not end:
        return []
    if not end:
        return [[start[0], math.inf]]
    if start[0] > end[0]:
        raise ValueError
    intervals = []
    current = start[0]
    i = 1
    j = 0
    while i < len(start) and j < len(end):
        if start[i] > end[j]:
            intervals.append([current, end[j]])
            current = start[i]
            j += 1
        i += 1
    if j < len(end) - 1:
        raise ValueError
    elif j == len(end) - 1:
        intervals.append([current, end[-1]])
    else:
        intervals.append([current, float("inf")])
    return intervals

start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
assert make_intervals(start, end) == [[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, 2019]]

start = [2010, 2011, 2015]
end = [2012, 2016, 2019]
try:
    make_intervals(start, end)
    assert False
except ValueError: pass

start = [2010, 2011, 2015, 2017, 2018]
end = [2012, 2016]
assert make_intervals(start, end) == [[2010, 2012], [2015, 2016], [2017, float("inf")]]
```